# Regular Expression for string replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have input string as below

`("abc xyz" OR "def") AND (ghi OR jkl)  AND ("mno poe" OR stu)`

i want it to replace with

`(myfun("abc xyz") OR myfun("def")) AND (myfun(ghi) OR myfun(jkl))  AND (myfun("mno poe") OR myfun(stu))`

i want that string with in double quotation mark or single word get replace with `myfun(<string matched>)`

can any body help me , how can i set this using regular expression ?
Thanks
Meghana

Comment: Thanks all , for replies.. all working.. but i can make only 1 as answer... but again thanks all for your inputs :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> reservedWords = new List<string>() { "AND","OR","NEAR","NOT" };
var rep = Regex.Replace(
            inputString,
            @"([\""][\w ]+[\""])|(\w+)",
            m=> reservedWords.Contains(m.Value) ? m.Value : "myfun(" + m.Value + ")" 
          );
```

Comment: hi.. it looks perfect , thanks for reply :) . i am going to try this :)

Answer (score 4):

The following C# quoted expression matches quoted strings and words that are not `AND` or `OR`:

```
@"(""(?:[^\\""]+|\\.)*""|\b(?!(?:AND|OR)\b)\w+\b)"
```

Replace it with:

```
"myfun($1)"
```

---

If all upper case words are operators, you can use this expression instead:

```
@"(""(?:[^\\""]+|\\.)*""|\b(?![A-Z]+\b)\w+\b)"
```

---

Updated to meet OPs new requirements the expression would look like:

```
@"(?i)(""(?:[^\\""]+|\\.)*""|\b(?!(?:and|or|not|near)\b)\w+\b)"
```

Added `(?i)` to make it case insensitive and completed the list of operator tokens.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply... but my logical operators can be AND , NOT , OR , NEAR .. .etc. also if that are specified with in double quotation , then i want them also to replace....  how can we specify in this regular exp??

Comment: Are all capital words reserved? In that case you don't need to list them. The expression above will match quoted, doesn't matter what its content is. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: hi Qtax... operators and my string can be in any case (lower or upper) .

Comment: Then you need to be more specific in your question. My answer will work for you original question. Anyway, how do we know which tokens are operators? What logic can be used? If listing them is acceptable then it could be an easy solution as in my first expression.

Comment: hi, sorry for confusion in my question . yes.... we have to list them. i can say and , or , not , near , ~  are operators

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
(".+?"|\b\w+?\b)(?<!(OR|AND))
```

with

```
myfun($1)
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply.. i sure try on this and back to u  :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        string input = "(\"abc xyz\" OR \"def\") AND (ghi OR jkl) AND (\"mno poe\" OR stu)";
        string expected = "(myfun(\"abc xyz\") OR myfun(\"def\")) AND (myfun(ghi) OR myfun(jkl)) AND (myfun(\"mno poe\") OR myfun(stu))";
        string actual = Regex.Replace(input, @"([\""\']).*?(\1)|\b(?!AND|OR)\w+\b", ReplaceWord);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    private static string ReplaceWord(Match m)
    {
        return string.Format("myfun({0})", m.Value);
    }
```

Comment: hi.. this looks what i needed ... i'll surely try this. Thanks :)

Comment: I should point out that this pattern is matching `"` or `'` and using a back reference so the value can be quoted with either.